# JSON (config file) with dynamic variables

Tags: json, node.js, docker, config

I'm using a node package called 'db-migrate' and it uses a database.json file as a databases configuration. The problem is we are starting to use Docker and I want to set the values as environment variables with fallback - for example:

```
{
 ...
 "host": process.env.DBHOST || 'localhost',
 ...
}
```

But how can I do it with a static json file?
I would like to use something similar to erb file with the dynamic abilities of template generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, better idea is to create a global config file like `config.js`, and put your configurations like

```
module.exports = {
    // APP SETTINGS
   ...
   "host": process.env.DBHOST || 'localhost',
   "port": process.env.DBPORT || '8080',
   ...
};
```

After doing this, you can easily access this file wherever you want.
For e.g. if you want to access these configurations in `app.js` file, then simply include it by adding a line in `app.js` file

```
var config = require('./config');
```

This will make the values available under `config` namespace and the values can be accessed as :

```
config.host or config.port
```

Hope the answer tells what you wanted.. 
If your intention is something else then please comment..

Comment: I know, and I use it in other files. The problem is that I use npm that use this file, and I can't change the file type or loading process.